# jQuery make DRY two almost identical on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a simple way to DRY this jQuery code?

```
  $('ul.icons li.size').click(function() {
    $('ul.icons li.size').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

  $('ul.icons li.color').click(function() {
    $('ul.icons li.color').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a group selector and just use `this` context to have the clicked list element:

```
  $('ul.icons li.size, ul.icons li.color').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('selected')      // add to clicked li
             .siblings('li')           // get all other lis
             .removeClass('selected');  // remove the class
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `.removeClass()` and `.toggleClass()`, I suggest gathering all of the elements that need to be toggled, and calling `.toggleClass()` once.

It would also be beneficial to give this functionality a name.  Since it seems like you want each group to have at most one item selected at any given time, I suggest `radioGroup()`.

```js
function radioGroup($set) {
  $set.click(function() {
    $set.filter('.selected').add(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
}

$(function() {
  radioGroup($('ul.icons li.size'));
  radioGroup($('ul.icons li.color'));
});
```

```css
.selected { background-color: black; color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="icons">
  <li>Sizes:
    <ul>
      <li class="size">Small</li>
      <li class="size">Medium</li>
      <li class="size">Large</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Color:
    <ul>
      <li class="color">Red</li>
      <li class="color">Green</li>
      <li class="color">Blue</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to assign the same piece of code on click on some $ selectors. Try something like this.

```
var selectors = ["ul.icons li.size","ul.icons li.color"];

selectors.forEach(function(item){  
  $(item).click(function() {
    $(item).not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');      
  });
});
```